# Django, replace adding an extra &emsp;?

Tags: python, django, replace

In my django models, I've been inputing some HTML. The HTML is showing up fine during output except one thing. Ive been using some shortcuts for things like "extra spaces" for my less technically inclined people using the admin:
Ie: if they write a & it gets replaced with an `&emsp;`

```
.replace("&","&emsp;")
```

Hoever, my querysets are outputting this instead:

```
&emsp;emsp;
```

Which has me confused. Any idea why I'm getting an extra emsp;? It's not looping and replacing the & a second time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have "&emsp" already in your html?

Well,

```
.replace("&","&emsp;")
```

would yield:

```
&emsp;emsp;
```

You need to ensure you're not running that replace method on something that already says "&emsp".

Comment: it turns out I had accidentally called the method twice. I guess I had only double checked the method itself before posting this :| ... thank you.